# Autosave PDF in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-office, make

This question is inspired by my use of LaTeX, where you usually share the generated PDF, not the source file. I want my `.docx` documents to be source files, with PDFs being the files to share. Thus I would like to have MS Word making a PDF with the same document name every time I save the `.docx` file. Is there a way to obtain such a behaviour? I'm on a mac, but it'd be nice to be able to do this on a Windows based computer as well.

Example: If I make a new document which I name `mydocument.docx`, then MS Word makes a copy in the same location named `mydocument.pdf`. The PDF will be saved and overwritten for each time I change and save `mydocument.docx`. A somewhat `make`-like action?

Comment: You can use doPdf but it won't work exactly how you desired. In this case every-time you need to print by making doPdf as the printing option.

Comment: It depends on how you create the PDF, but you would create some macro which saves the .docx and then also creates the PDF. It would essentially do what you would do manually.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this by overriding the `Save` and `SaveAs` macros which are called when the user activates those two functions from the editor. This should work in all version of Word that supports saving directly as PDF, which is Microsoft Word 2007 SP2 and up (including Word for Mac 2008 and up).

The full macro to acheive this is below, insert it into your active template so it will work with all documents you create.

There is an error handler which lets you know if the operation failed (most likely because you have the PDF open which gets locked for viewing). If there is any problems catching the events you could also try Application Events in place of the overrides.

```
' Override File -> Save
Public Sub FileSave()

    ActiveDocument.Save
    SaveActiveDocumentAsPdf

End Sub

' Override File -> Save As...
Public Sub FileSaveAs()

    ActiveDocument.SaveAs
    SaveActiveDocumentAsPdf

End Sub

Sub SaveActiveDocumentAsPdf()

    On Error GoTo Errhandler

    If InStrRev(ActiveDocument.FullName, ".") <> 0 Then

        Dim strPath As String
        strPath = Left(ActiveDocument.FullName, InStrRev(ActiveDocument.FullName, ".") - 1) & ".pdf"

        ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strPath, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    Exit Sub

Errhandler:

    MsgBox "There was an error saving a copy of this document as PDF. " & _
    "Ensure that the PDF is not open for viewing and that the destination path is writable. Error code: " & Err

End Sub
```

Comment: Great! I believe this is something I'm looking for. When I've made the macro and I try to save a file (with or without an existing PDF) I get error code 438...

Comment: @Holene, Yes I did some reading and it looks like the method SaveAs2 is only supported on Word 2010 and above, so I have made an edit to use the SaveAs method instead (pretty much the same thing), give it a try. Take note about the required version of Word 2007 as described above though.

Comment: I'm on Word 2011 for Mac. Should it still be a problem?

Comment: I don't have any experience with Word for Mac but just to make sure, did you fix this line? ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strPath, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF. Do you still get the same error?

Comment: Getting error 4198 now... And now I'm not able to specify saving location.